# NODE_ENV is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, windows-10, git-bash

I am trying to set up a Node Express server with some basic routes and I have some unit tests to run against them. But when I try to run the tests I get the following error.

```
'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

The npm scripts for the same are

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=testing jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles  --silent",
"test-routes": "npm run test -t router",
```

I am on a Windows machine, using Visual Studio Code with its **integrated terminal pointing to Git-Bash**.

I thought since I am using git-bash, `NODE_ENV=testing` should work automatically. But it doesn't.

When I change the script to

```
"test": "SET NODE_ENV=testing jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles  --silent",
```

the error goes away but tests are not running.

```
$ yarn test-routes
yarn run v1.17.3
$ npm run test -t router

> api-design-v3@1.0.0 test D:\learning_workspace\api-design-node-v3
> set NODE_ENV=testing jest --detectOpenHandles "router"

Done in 1.70s.
```

Comment: That's not how you set env vars inline on Windows; I'd suggest using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env. Also note you need `--` to pass extra arguments when you use npm run; you can see in the last output that `-t` didn't make it through.

Comment: What @jonrsharpe said was true, you can also try https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv